# In java, how can I handle exceptions regarding Windows command line arguments?

Tags: java, exception, command-line, user-input

I looked through a bunch of other questions and online, but I can't find anything that answers this specifically. I'm trying to handle dealing with and determining valid input based on a Windows command line argument. As a sample, I was just seeing if an entered number was positive to be as easy as possible. The biggest issue, and what made me unable to find a specific answer, was I'm really trying to use recursion to make it keep asking until a valid input is entered, rather than just killing the program.

```
Algorithm:
If there is an argument provided and it's a positive integer
    Display value
Otherwise
    Until the argument is a positive number
        Prompt for a positive integer
    Display value
```

I wrestled with the code and eventually got this to work, but it seems really inefficient, repetitive and hacked together. At first, I had the while-loop inside the caught exceptions, but this allowed other things to slip through from the command line. How can I make this as efficient as possible and also prevent any logic errors or exceptions? What approach should I take with my algorithm when tackling this? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String arg;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;

        try {
            arg = args[0];
            i = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            arg = "";
        } catch( NumberFormatException e2 ) {
            arg = "";
        }

        while( i <= 0 )
        {
            System.out.print("Please type in a positive whole number.  ");
            arg = user_input.next();

            try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch( NumberFormatException e2 ) {
                System.out.print("That's a letter! ");
                continue;
            }

            if( i <= 0 )
            {
                System.out.print("That's a negative. ");
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Input is " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The code is quite lengthy this is because two separate try blocks are required; one for the command-line argument & the other for the argument provided via the scanner...

I had to create my own custom exception, "NegativeNumberException"...

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NegativeNumberException extends Exception{

        NegativeNumberException(){
            System.out.println(exceptionMessage);
        }

        String exceptionMessage = "Number must be positive";
        static int num;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws NegativeNumberException{

            try
            {
            if(Integer.parseInt(args[0])<0){
                throw new NegativeNumberException();
            }
            else{
                 int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                 System.out.println("Your number is: " + num);

            }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                System.out.println("That's not even a number.");

            }
            catch(NegativeNumberException ex){
                ex.getMessage();
            }



            while(num==0){
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter a positive number:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                int num1 = input.nextInt();
                if(num1<0){
                    throw new NegativeNumberException();
                }
                num = num1;
                break;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Positive number only, try again...");
                }
            }//End While

            System.out.println("Your number is:" + num);
            }

    }
```

---

**Input:** (Command-line): lol

**Output**

```
       (Console):That's not even a number
                  Enter a positive int

       (Console input via Scanner): -4

       (Console):Number must be positive
                 Positive number only, try again...
                 Enter a positive number:

       (Console input via Scanner): 3


       (Console):Your number is: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Creating a brand new exception is a little bit beyond my current experience, so I hadn't thought of it, but this definitely answers my problem in the most succinct, elegant and efficient manner and also builds in a safety net on the compiler level. I really appreciate it! Now I just need to learn how to make exceptions well :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried, but I don't have enough reputation yet. You were certainly helpful though, and I did choose your answer as the Accepted Answer if that helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so that it runs the way you want.  Try using this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String arg;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numTries = 0, value = 0;

    try {
        numTries = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);      // get max number of tries
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        arg = "";
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
        arg = "";
    }

    // try 'numTries' times to read a valid number input
    for (int i=numTries; i > 0; --i) {
        System.out.print("Please type in a positive whole number: ");
        arg = user_input.next();

        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e2) {
            System.out.println("That's a letter! ");
            continue;
        }

        if (value <= 0) {
            System.out.println("That's a negative. ");
        }
        break;                                     // exit loop if number input found
    }

    System.out.println("Input is " + value);
}
```

This code has been tested on IntelliJ and it runs with no problems.